# How to identify consecutive lines with specific features using for loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, file-io

I am now manipulating huge data set. The format is like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 A 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 A 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 A 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 B 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 B 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 C 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 C 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 C 1 1 1 1
```

'1' can be different. My goal is to identify the two lines with 'B' (three or four consecutive lines with 'B' is possible) and extract these lines with 'B' and their surrounding lines (e.g., the prior two lines with 'A' and the following two lines with 'C'). There are several blocks of this kind and I was considering using for loop to read the file line by line. Every time when I meet an 'A' followed by a 'B' the position is identified. I tried using

```
for line in file:
    if 'A' in line and if 'B' in file.next():
```

But it seemed some lines were lost. My question is how can I exactly identify A-B (or B-C) line pair using for loop? And after that, how can I easily go backwards (or forwards) several lines to extract all of them within the loop?

Comment: The basic problem occurs because `file.next()` actually reads the line, so it won't be picked up on the next iteration of the loop. But you still have a much more complicated problem than the small amount of code you show can address. For the general approach to this sort of problem, see if you get any ideas from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine .

Comment: But if you do decide that you want to be able to jump around and look at each line in the file in whatever order you like, the easiest way is to get a `list` that has each line of the file as a separate element. This is as easy as you can imagine it to be: `lines = list(file)`.

Comment: How 'huge' is huge dataset? Can it either easily fit in memory or not?

Comment: Is the item in question always the 9th element on the line?

Comment: Also, how many surrounding lines do you need?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The data set is whole genome sequence. The number of surrounding lines depends on specific locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `linecache` module can get lines from a file by line number. You can use this to mark boundary points (A-B, B-C) as you go through the file, and then loop through the lines to get the output that you want.

```
import linecache

final_lines = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if "B" in line:
            if "A" in linecache.getline("file.txt", i-1):
                linestart = i - 2  ##2 lines before
            if "C" in linecache.getline("file.txt", i+1):
                lineend = i + 2  ##2 lines after
                for j in range(linestart, lineend+1):
                    final_lines.append(linecache.getline("file.txt", j))
print(final_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to do this and each has its advantages and disadvantages. One way to do this would be to keep a running storage of lines you've already gone over but only if they meet a certain criteria. For example, let's say you read a line with 'A' in it. You start storing these lines in an array until you either hit another letter or a 'B' if you hit a 'B' then you can permanently store or output or whatever it is you're wanting to do with this data. If you hit a different letter than you can erase the cache. A possible implementation might look like this.

```
# Create our temporary storage and final output
cache = []
output_data = []

for line in file:
    # If we find an A lets keep that line in case we find a B after
    if 'A' in line:
        cache.append(line)
    # If we find a B then we take what's in the cache and put it in our final output
    elsif 'B' in line:
        output_data.extend(cache)
        output_data.append(line)  # Add the B line
        cache = [] # We no longer need what was stored here and dont want to store it multiple times if there are more 'B's next.
    else:
        cache = []
```

This doesn't take into account the B-C scenario but as you can see this is one possible solution to try for. The disadvantage to this is memory usage. If you had a file that was full of 'A's and at the end no 'B' then you would have stored the entire file in memory while waiting to find a B.

The solution I would probably take is to store the number of the line instead of the line itself in temporary memory. Then iterate over the final again at the end to output all the lines that I'm interested in. The advantage is less memory use but the disadvantage is speed (reads file twice).

Comment: Thank you for your help! The idea is really easy to understand. But in your example it seems all lines with 'A' will be appended to the next line with 'B'. I think it needs some modifications to meet my needs. I will try to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I might not understand your needs correctly than. I thought the purpose was to grab all previously sequential 'A' lines if they were followed by a 'B' line.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is not really to go forwards and backwards in the file, but instead to keep track of where you are logically in the process, and the data involved.

This is the algorithm we will use:

- Keep a "buffer" of lines. To start, we are in the "look for A" state.
- In the "look for A" state, if we find an "A" line, we append it to the buffer, and we also remove the first line in the buffer if there were already 2 lines (i.e. we keep a maximum of 2). If we find a "B" line, then we go to the "append all the Bs" state, as well as handling that line. Otherwise, we found some other garbage, and we empty the buffer (because we didn't find what we're looking for).
- In the "append all the Bs" state, we keep appending "B" lines to the buffer until we find a "C" line, or whatever.

And so on. The details of this depend on how you want to do all your error handling... like, do there have to be at least two "A" lines before, and at least two "C" lines after? What if the line doesn't contain any of those things? Etc. etc.

But the basic approach is simple: use a variable to remember the "state" (arguably the easiest way is to use a string), and then `for` each line, you use `if` logic to do the appropriate thing for each state - whether it's building up the buffer, resetting the buffer, changing the state, etc.

At the end of this, the buffer should have the lines you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear description of the concept and the logic in working on my problems. It really helps me to understand the workflow of the language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have really huge files to do the extraction, I don't suggest using python, in fact you can just use awk or the grep command to do all that on linux.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will have a try since I also know something about shell.